# copying strings to the list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, copy, append

I have a list `data`, and I am reading lines from it.

```
item = user = channel = time = []
with open('train_likes.csv') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    readlines = f.readlines()
```

I want to split each line into single string elements and append each element to a one of 2 other lists: `user`, `items`

```
    for line in readlines:
        Type = line.split(",")
        Copy1 = Type[0]
        Copy2 = Type[1]
        user.append(Copy1)
        item.append(Copy2)
```

But when appending `item`, `user` is appended with `Copy2` as well, and `item` got the same as `user`!!!

[image: user's and item's value's]

I have checked all familiar replies, but that didn't help me (I tried to copy everything in the script, here's only one version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `item=user=channel=time=[]`, you are creating only one object, with 4 aliases. So appending to `item` is the same as appending to `user`. Instead you should write

```
item, user, channel, time = [], [], [], []
```

or simply

```
item = []
user = []
channel = []
time = []
```

Comment: OMG, I love YOU so MUCH!

Answer (score 2):

As @Greg points out, you are creating one list object and assigning it to four variables.

You don't appear to use `channel` or `time` in your code, however.  In addition, this is a more memory efficient way to read your file.  You are reading each line separately instead of the whole file at once.

```
item = []
user = []
with open('train_likes.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        # Splits on whitespace taking at most three splits (with zero indexing, 2 equals 3...).
        u, i, _ = ", ".join(line).split(", ", 2)  
        item.append(i.strip())
        user.append(u.strip())
```

Comment: thnak You for your advice,sir!

Comment: Actually, while debugging yoyr variant, i get this error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
for the line: u, i, _ = line.split(None, 2)